# How to set the percentage at which my MacBook warns about low battery?

Tags: terminal, battery, macos, notifications

Mine gives a warning at 5% and I'd be much happier if it could warn me at 10%. I assume there's either a way to do in the `System Preferences` or I have to set a value to some variable in `Terminal`.

I've been researching for it for a while, but I couldn't solve it myself. Please tell me how I can set it.

---

*(Operating system: **macOS Sierra** Version 10.12.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you weren't aware and/or haven't tried this, you can:

- click on the battery icon in the menu bar
- in the dropdown menu that appears, click "Show"
- select whether you want the remaining time or percentage displayed

This will display the remaing time or remaining percentage to the right of the battery icon. It is always visible in the menu bar, making it easy to glance at regularly.

With regard the warning, I'm a little surprised it's only triggering at 5%. However, it is designed to trigger once your MacBook is running on reserve power and perhaps in your case that's at 5% because of the overall battery life.

Comment: Yeah I knew about this option. I did display it for a while, but usually I'm focusing on my work and I'd rather get warnings/notifications.  
I'm pretty sure it's 10% by default and I changed it a while back. I just cannot remember how I did it.